# C# Error when pressing the Enter key - program crashes

Tags: c#, crash, enter

I stupidly closed a question that I thought was answered recently, but I've hit another issue.

My code crashes when enter is pressed without a character being input. Is there a way to prevent this? The error message if the user inputs the **wrong** character works, but it crashes if enter is pressed without any input placed.

The error message I get is **An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: String must be exactly one character long.**

Here is my code:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace computerPackage
{
    class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char computerPackage;
            const decimal DELUXE_PACKAGE = 1500;
            const decimal SUPER_PACKAGE = 1700;
            Console.Write("Input the Computer Package D or S: ");
            computerPackage = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            computerPackage = Char.ToUpper(computerPackage);
            if (computerPackage == 'D')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cost of Deluxe Computer Package is " + DELUXE_PACKAGE.ToString("C"));
            }
            else if (computerPackage == 'S')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cost of Deluxe Computer Package is " +
                SUPER_PACKAGE.ToString("C"));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Package D or S not entered");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();          // pause
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _computerPackage = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());_  [FormatException 
The length of s is not 1.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Read it in and then check the length and then parse the 1st character only!

Comment: Bit confused as to what exactly to write mate. Any chance you could elaborate?

Comment: Basically what Zubair writes: Your code is to short. You need to take it apart and add in the missing checks why do you use ReadLine instead of Read or ReadKey?!

Answer (score 1):

after you press enter without any character, your program tries to Parse an empty string which is not possible and will give exception. Create check before parsing like this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char computerPackage;
        const decimal DELUXE_PACKAGE = 1500;
        const decimal SUPER_PACKAGE = 1700;
        Console.Write("Input the Computer Package D or S: ");
        string inp = Console.ReadLine();
        if (inp.Length==1)
        {
            computerPackage = Char.Parse(inp);
            computerPackage = Char.ToUpper(computerPackage);
            if (computerPackage == 'D')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cost of Deluxe Computer Package is " + DELUXE_PACKAGE.ToString("C"));
            }
            else if (computerPackage == 'S')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cost of Deluxe Computer Package is " +
                SUPER_PACKAGE.ToString("C"));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Package D or S not entered");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Package D or S not entered");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: So this takes care of the crashing, but it doesn't display the error message that I had defined if a wrong character was entered as here:                 Console.WriteLine("Package D or S not entered");
Instead it just closes the program altogether. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: This should also crash when more than one character is entered. ReadKey is the more natural choice I'd say..

Comment: I have edited the code. Just keep in mind that char.Parse is possible for length 1 only so keep check on it that input length should be 1.also if you need to display any error then change your code according to your requirements.